# How can i check effectively whether a path string is a child of another path string in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check whether a path (which is a string) is a child of another path (a string) in jQuery. For Eg:

```
var path1 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\New  Discovery\F1\F10\F1";
var path2 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery";
```

In this case i should get the result as true. Eg 2:

```
var path1 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery123\New  Discovery\F1\F10\F1";
var path2 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery";
```

In this case i should get the result as false. Eg. 3:

```
var path1 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\New  Discovery\F1\F10\F1";
var path2 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\";
```

In this case i should get the result as true.

I tried `indexOf()` and `search()`, both of them fails in second and third example. Both of these methods also fails in case of multiple words or spaces. Below is the code that i have tried:

```
   var path1 = "\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\New  Discovery\F1\F10\F1";
   var n = path1.indexOf("\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\");
```

Comment: if you want 'n' to be true or false >> var n = path1.indexOf("\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery\")>-1

Comment: It fails in eg 2 and 3 as i have mentioned. It's not just true or false, i want to be able to search path in any manner.

Comment: try removing the slashes from the beginning and end of your indexOf condition

Comment: as in >> var n = path1.indexOf("\\192.168.30.102\Test Share\Discovery");

Comment: @webkit: I can't remove the slashes as the paths i get are absolute path from server. Even if i remove the slashes from beginning or end, slashes in between can't be removed, and it fails in second case when the last word will have extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change your input format as following. The reason is "\" is the escape character and to put "\" in a string you have to escape "\" by replacing it with "\\"

```
var path1 = "\\\\192.168.30.102\\Test Share\\Discovery\\New  Discovery\\F1\\F10\\F1";
var path2 = "\\\\192.168.30.102\\Test Share\\Discovery";
```

Then you may use following function,

```
function isChildPath(parent, url){
    if(parent.indexOf(url) == 0){
        if (parent.charAt(url.length - 1) == "\\" || parent.charAt(url.length) == "\\")
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

to check if path2 is a child of path1,

```
isChildPath(path1,path2);
```

Comment: I am getting path from the server. Since "\" is a escape character, i am not able to replace "\" with "\\".

Comment: @Saket How do you get the path from server to client? Via ajax? Can't you change the string sent by the server to match this format from server side?

Comment: The function -- that returns server path -- is used by other modules too. So, changing the string at server will effect other modules. Can't it be done without changing anything on the server side?